# Parcel React How do i fix the set up error?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, parceljs

my index.js file

When i run a parcel/ react project i keep getting the error below

> @parcel/transformer-js: Unexpected token `)`. Expected this, import, async, function, [ for array
> literal, { for object literal, @ for decorator, function, class, null, true, false, number,
> bigint, string, regexp, ` for template literal, (, or an identifier

```js
  import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
    import App from './App/App';
    
    
    const container = document.getElementById('root');
    
    const root = createRoot(container); 
    // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript
    root.render(<App/>);
```

//index.html file

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1.0">
    <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>
        My App
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root">

    </div>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js">
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

/// my app.js file is below

```js
  export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className=''>
        <h2 className='text-green-700 '>
Analytics
        </h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

my package.json file

```js
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "parcel": "2.4",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react-google-charts": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "name": "analytics",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Analytic app",
    "source": "src/index.html",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "parcel",
        "build": "parcel build"
    },
    "author": "Caldewood Alikula",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You forgot to import `App`?

Comment: Yes but after adding  i still get the same error

Comment: Can you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? When I tried re-creating the problem with the details that are visible from the screenshot, I don't see the error. Some things that would be good to know are: what does your `package.json` look like? What does your index.html look like?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid include `react` and `react-dom` via CDN.

1. Install them as `npm` packages:

```bash
npm i react@16.6.3
npm i react-dom@16.6.3
```

2. Restart the server